# iOS Keyboard doesn't resign until after view transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikeyboard, resignfirstresponder

I have set this `UIViewController` to be the delegate for the `UITextField` in the `viewDidLoad` with this line: `self.nameInputTextField.delegate = self;`.

I **have** set the delegate on the class as well by adding `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to the `@interface` declaration.

When I select the nextButton, in the method that is called, I have tried `[self.nameInputTextField resignFirstResponder]` as well as `[self.view endEditing:YES]` one line before I push the new view controller.

The rest of the class does not manipulate the firstResponder.

I've also implemented the UITextField delegate method

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.nameInputTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
```

I haven't found any related questions after extensive searching.  There are many similar ones about resigning keyboards, but not regarding the timing of the keyboard resignation being postponed until after the view transition is complete.  Note- if you reload this url in your browser, you'll see the gif again from the beginning.

[image]

Comment: can you see your code?

Comment: please share code sample you are using in your project.

Comment: I can't share much, it's surrounded by uniquely identifying code in a security app.  Sorry.

Comment: try [textField resignFirstResponder]; remove [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder]

Comment: check this method : - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField; and also put breakpoint this method call.

Comment: if you can not share code than how we can solve your problem

Comment: @DarjiJigar I am an experienced enough iOS developer to know that the amount of information that I've included is all that is relevant to this issue.

Comment: you can try to replace [textField resignFirstResponder]; to [self.nameInputTextField resignFirstResponder];

Comment: @jungledev First thing 1) you have set myTextField.delegate = self  i think you already did this 2) Please in you code method replace return No; with  return YES;  See its working or not.

Comment: Check Constraints, It might be the problem of your leading or trailing constraint. It happened with me too while transitioning,I changed my constraints and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Hide keyboard anywhere in ios :**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UIView * txt in self.view.subviews){
        if ([txt isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] && [txt isFirstResponder]) {
            [txt resignFirstResponder];
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Didn't work.  I was really hoping it would, and it definitely looks like it should!

Comment: you don't need to call this method , just write this method and debug through breakpoint and you can fix your problem.

because it's works well..

Comment: As you are using UIScrollView you might not able to get touches method for UIScrollView. In that case you might have to use UIGesture.

Comment: Why do you think I'm using UIScrollView?  This is absolutely not a UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Resign your keyboard on `viewWillDisappear` and the problem should be solved.

**Edit**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.nameInputTextField.text = @"";
    [self.nameInputTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Nope, didn't fix it.  Tried that already, but I just tried it again per your suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure you called the `super viewWillDisappear` because I had similar problem and I tackled it in similar fashion. Maybe you should empty the textfield as well. I even added the code for you. Give it a try. :)

Comment: FYI, I can read Swift just fine, but it's nice if you submit a solution in the same language the question is asked in.  `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    [self.nameInputTextField resignFirstResponder];
}`

Comment: Sorry my bad. I had the code in Swift and just shifted it here. Will correct it.